# How do you finely dice an onion without crying?

Tags: onions, knife-skills

[This question addresses onion crying](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/567/how-can-i-chop-onions-without-crying)

But no one seems to say what should you do when you finely chop an onion. See, not cutting the onion core, using the Gordon Ramsay technique and generally pivoting away from the onion helped so far. But now I have upped my dicing skills. I can chop finer, but alas I am a victim of my own success where the smell of the fine onion is almost like the obscenity of grated onion (horrible).

Sharp knife, not cutting to the core, pivoting away etc all stop working when you are good enough to fine dice an onion. Short of goggles, what do you do?

---

Comment: I think this is still a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @ Debbie M. I agree. Finely chopping onions and just chopping onions is absolutely the same thing.

Comment: @debbiem. not quite since the more finely an onion is chopped the more severe is the tear gas it is spreading.

Comment: They're not exactly the same thing -- when dicing the onion, I also take a few other precautions: (1) prep the onions  (take off blossom end, peel, cut in half and place cut-side down on cutting board but **do not** cut the root end).  (2) do the initial cuts  (I tend to do diagonal rather than vertical & horizontal, but whatever you like ... the goal is to keep the onion together).  (3) do the final cross-cuts, but keep the onion together (this requires a *really* sharp knife, and holding both sides of the onion as you're cutting). ... the goal is to *not* expose cut, wet surfaces.

Comment: TL;DR from the chaotic set of answers to the linked question: Crush cells as little as possible. Do so by using sharp and thin tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breathe through your mouth.

The tear-causing chemicals in onions are absorbed through the nasal mucous membrane. By breathing through your mouth, they don't get much contact with the fumes and won't absorb nearly as much.

Comment: I'd actually rather see this as an answer on the linked question, because it's equally relevant to chopping onions in general.

Comment: @logophobe I'm pretty sure a diamond-mod (contacted by flagging for mod intervention) can move the answer over. Philipp however cannot, except by pasting it in as a new answer. [Not doing myself as I have no idea if its a good answer—note the other question has an answer saying the opposite!]